# Laravel 5.5の開発環境で「ORCHID」のインストール

Tags: php, laravel-5, cms

https://orchid.software/en/docs/requirements/
を参考にしてインストールしていますが、うまくいきません。

> ### User
>
> Inherit your model App\User
>
> ```
> namespace App;
>
> use Orchid\Platform\Core\Models\User as BaseUser;
>
> class User extends BaseUser
> {
>
> }
> ```

という部分が分からず困っています。

開発環境は
Windows10 Vagrant HomeStead VirtualBoxで構築しています。

結果は
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
となります。

なかなか前に進まず困っています

宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: その部分が「どう分からなくて困っている」のか、逆に何が分かっているか明確化されるといいかもしれません。また、結果は～ってなんの結果なのかこの文脈では分からないのですが……

Comment: このモデルの継承ってどういう意味なのかが分かりません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/111748

Answer (score 0):

change the address of the page you are accessing in [`config/platform`](https://github.com/orchidsoftware/platform/blob/master/config/platform.php#L27)

Sorry, but the documentation in Russian covers more nuances

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your model App\User, this means replacing the contents of the file
App\User.php

You can also use the [installer](https://github.com/orchidcommunity/Installer)